# Best practices to fill view models with select lists and options for views' reusability in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using view models over models. Let's say we have an edit form for some entity. Let's say that form has a field which is selected from drop down list. What is the best way to fill list used for generating that drop down list? Should it be done in get action in controller or maybe in the constructor of the view model or somewhere else?

My next doubt is view models "configuring". I'm trying to reuse my views so when I have an edit form it should be possible to use it in add and update scenarios. My submit button should then execute two different actions. Is it okay to parametrize a view by adding to a view model controller and action names?

Finally when I have my view models which are storing all those data - its "configuration" is quite vast. Is there any good pattern to get this logic out of the controller? I'm using some kind of builders, but I'm not sure whether it's good enough.

Answer (score 2):

First of all excuse me if I won't be exhaustive but topic is pretty vast. Please read this *cum grano salis*, nothing is a rule written in the stone then things must be adapted case by case to each specific scenario.

> What is the best way to fill list used for generating that drop down list? Should it be done in get action in controller or maybe in the constructor of the view model or somewhere else?

Controller method(s). I like to **keep model** (underlying *model* or *view model*) **as simple as possible (ideally merely an entity)** because model isn't place for logic (even if this can be relaxed for underlying model because in domain objects logic and data are often tied together).

Moreover list items may be added/removed according to many factors and this will span logic across controllers and model.

Imagine you have following requirement: *"design a view where user can pick a movie from a list, list is populated using his past history to pick best candidates; provide a dropdown to filter movies by category"*. There is a lot of logic here, search in history, some kind of smart algorithm to pick best candidates and finally your function to prepare list. Of course if there isn't any *Drama* movie you wouldn't put that item in the list. If you put *something* in the model then you'll finally have to put *everything* there, leaving Controller as a stupid entity that merely create a Model instance and pick right View. Too little, especially because Controller methods are **easy to be reused** between Views but model classes are pretty more specific.

Moreover here I would also **move list itself out of the model**. I like to keep model focused on *real objects*, what user will see and what he selects (so, if I need it, I don't worry to simply JSON serialize them). If you have some model classes with logic and some others without (because they're JSON results, for example) then you'll find to search for your logic both in Model and Controller. Pretty confusing. Available options (like movie categories in previous example) are View specific details that I like to keep in `ViewBag`.

> Is it okay to parametrize a view by adding to a view model controller and action names?

Yes it's OK *per se* but you should ask yourself if it's not better to extract a `PartialView`, they'll be embedded in outer View and it'll be automatic; assuming you have the *typical* pattern:

```
ActionResult Edit() { }

[HttpPost] Edit(Model data) { }
```

> ...view models which are storing all those data... Is there any good pattern to get this logic out of the controller?

I can't give here a decent answer because it depends on your case. If your view logic is very complex you may need to introduce a thin layer to encapsulate all these stuff (Controller will interact with them and put things together but it won't be aware of logic specific details).

Storing data (model <-> view model) is somehow easier, sometimes (often? almost always?) a good OOM like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper) will solve most of your problems (without all the issues you usually have with ORMs). Mapping is done by convention and if you follow it then you won't need to write more than few lines of code (and for very complicated cases it can be configured).

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree with your opinion about keeping models simple, but for a while I had a doubt that maybe it's good to fill mentioned lists in constructors. On the other hand I'm not convinced about ViewBag usage. I vaguely see another, but more complicated option - keeping in the model only result of selection, and whole drop down list could be dynamically loaded by consuming a JSON by calling some method of the web service (or web API).

Comment: Yes it's also viable (especially good for long lists) but it'll not _integrate_ very well with existing MVC Html.DropDownListFor() methods (because selected value will be assigned before list is actually constructed). It works better if you do most things on client side. Anyway don't forget you can have a Model for your controller and a Tuple<ListModel, Model> for your view (in case you really don't like ViewBag).

Comment: I didn't know about Tuple option, I used rather nested models, thank you.